# Metasploit cannot load such file -- nmap/xml

Tags: ruby, xml, nmap, metasploit

Msfconsole has been working fine, all of a sudden I get this error. It also states:

Load error: Make sure the Ruby gems are installed properly, run bundle install- which I did and after fiddling with it, it completed successfully. Any tips?

Comment: are you using bundler, means you have a GemFile?

Comment: Yes. I'm in Kali..should've clarified that earlier :/

Comment: then add `ruby-nmap` to your gemfile, and then do bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:-

install `ruby-nmap` gem

```
  gem install ruby-nmap
```

Comment: So far, that's a no-go as well.

Comment: Metasploit uses a custom nokogiri XML parser for Nmap output, not `ruby-nmap`